# Reconfigure multitenant container on the fly in Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, multi-tenant

I need to update configuration of tenants in multitenant container. Can I do it with Autofac or I should implement custom container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the contents of the multitenant container for a tenant you've already set up is not supported. You can [add registrations to a child lifetime scope](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#adding-registrations-to-a-lifetime-scope) spun off of a tenant scope, but you can't change the tenant scope without rebuilding the container. In general, [you should treat a container as immutable](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/best-practices/index.html#consider-a-container-as-immutable) - once you've built it and resolved something from it, you shouldn't change it.

Comment: I got it. But will it be incorrect if I will create new multitenant container with new registrations?

Comment: I don't understand your follow up question. Long story short: If you resolve something from a container, you're stuck with it. If you need to change the contents of the container, you need a new container. This means you need to dispose of the old container, which usually also means app restart. Not disposing of the old container or keeping a mix of old resolved items and new resolved items puts your app in an inconsistent state - things that aren't sharing the correct set of dependencies anymore.